# Scrolling bar on IE using devexpress

Tags: javascript, gridview, devexpress, scrollbar

I use devexpress gridview with vertical scroll bar, when the user focus on record of the gridview and press down arrow the focuse move to the next record but the scroll bar dosen't move
I write this code in javascript to make scroll bar moving and record focused still visible to me it works on firefox and chrome but doesn't work on IE 11 is there any way to deal with scroll bar in gridview in IE

```
document.onkeydown=function(e){
 e=(e || event)
 If(e.keyCode == 40){
     var ix = grid.GetFocusedRowIndex();
     var v= grid.GetVisibleRowOnPage();
     if(((ix%2==0) || (ix%3==0)) && (ix!=2)){
           return true;
       }
     e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need to also use DX ASPxGridView JS scroll helpers like:

[ASPxClientGridView.SetVerticalScrollPosition](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientGridView_SetVerticalScrollPositiontopic) - to set the vertical scroll position
[ASPxClientGridView.GetVerticalScrollPosition](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientGridView_GetVerticalScrollPositiontopic) - to get vertical scroll position

These methods should be IE11 compatible since they are included in the official release.

See more details in the following post:

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q523412

HTH